# Try... except is wrong

Tags: python, debugging, try-except

I was working on a function that test functions and I found that y try except was wrong at all... In fact, when I am trying to test a sorting function (the one by selection) it returns me that the index was out of range and it's not the case when I try the function independently with the same list...

Here is the code :

```py
def verifyList(L: list) -> bool:
    for elm in range(len(L)):
        if L[elm] > L[elm + 1]:
            return False
        #
    return True

def tri_selection(L: list) -> list:
    """
    Recupere un element et l'échange avec le un plus grand
    """
    assert type(L) == list
    
    for i in range(len(L)):
        for j in range(len(L)):
            if L[i] <= L[j]:
                L[j], L[i] = L[i], L[j]
            #
        #
    #
    return L
```

Other functions that are not written because it's unnecessary...

```
def __test__(L: list) -> str:
    assert type(L) == list

    functionsToTry = [tri_selection]

    for function in functionsToTry:
        try:
            if verifyList(function(L)) == True:
                print('[✓] ' + str(function.__name__) + ' : worked successfuly')
            else:
                print('[≃] ' + str(function.__name__) + ' : do not worked successfuly')
                continue
        except Exception as error:
            print('[✕] ' + str(function.__name__) + ' : ' + str(error))
        else:
            print(function(L))
__test__([3, 2, 1])
```

If you have an idea I'll be glad to know it,

Thx

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that others can actually run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I would assume the issue is inside the 'verifyList' function, which you unfortunately did not reproduce here.

Comment: Sorry you are right, I'll give you something more, I'll also change the list, that now contain only the function that bugs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if L[elm] > L[elm + 1]:` gives a list index out of range error when `elm == len(L) - 1`. The easiest fix is to change `verifyList` to:

```
def verifyList(L: list) -> bool:
    return L == sorted(L)
```

With this change your function passes the test.

Comment: You are right, I just saw the probleme, I am an idiot, thx